# Numerical approach to find curvature

Tags: numerical-methods, curvature, finite-differences, finite-difference-methods

Suppose I have two arrays of real numbers $x[i]$, $y[i]$ which can be considered as some smooth 2D curve points.

How can I find array of its curvature approximate values in each node $k[i]$?

Answer (score 0):

There have been papers written on this topic. Here is one, which can lead you
to others:

> Anoshkina, Elena V., Alexander G. Belyaev, and Hans-Peter Seidel. "Asymtotic Analysis of Three-Point Approximations of Vertex Normals and Curvatures." *VMV*. 2002.
>
> ---
>
> [image]
>   
>             
>   
>   <sup>Figure from Belyaev, "A note on invariant three-point curvature approximations (...)." (1999).</sup>

---